# Modular Scala design: how do I avoid a constructor "push-out" boilerplate?

Tags: scala, boilerplate

Perhaps a Scala expert with a good sense of style and elegance can help me figure out a nicer way to structure the following code, which has a constructor "push-out" problem.

We start with a simple base class:

```
class Foo(val i: Int, val d: Double, val s: String) {

  def add(f: Foo) = new Foo(i + f.i, d + f.d, s + f.s)
  override def toString = "Foo(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)

}
```

For type-checking purposes in a complex application, I require a sub-class without any additional state:

```
class Bar(i: Int, d: Double, s: String) extends Foo(i,d,s) {

  override def toString = "Bar(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)

}
```

As it stands, when I add two Bars, I only get back a Foo:

```
val x = new Bar(1,2.3,"x")
val y = new Bar(4,5.6,"y")
val xy = x.add(y)
```

with the following response in the REPL:

```
x  : Bar = Bar(1,2.300000,x)
y  : Bar = Bar(4,5.600000,y)
xy : Foo = Foo(5,7.900000,xy)
```

How do I get two Bars to add together to form another Bar (rather than a Foo), in an elegant way, without having to copy and paste Foo's add method, as below?

```
class Bar(i: Int, d: Double, s: String) extends Foo(i,d,s) {

  // ugly copy-and-paste from Foo:
  def add(b: Bar) = new Bar(i + b.i, d + b.d, s + b.s)
  override def toString = "Bar(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)

}
```

I have many such Bars (all essentially copies of Foo, but very important for type checking), a cut-and-paste-free solution will pay dividends.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I try to avoid inheritance as much as possible. So here is an alternative approach.

Class `Bar` has exactly the same constructor than `Foo` and both are stateless. If you want to have several sub-types, just to convey any additional information, you can use a generic parameter as a "label". For instance:

```
trait Kind
trait Bar extends Kind

class Foo[T<:Kind](val i: Int, val d: Double, val s: String) {
   def add(f: Foo[T]) = new Foo[T](i + f.i, d + f.d, s + f.s)
   override def toString = "Foo(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)
}


scala> val b1 = new Foo[Bar](2,3.0,"hello")
b1: Foo[Bar] = Foo(2,3.000000,hello)

scala> val b2 = new Foo[Bar](3,1.0," world")
b2: Foo[Bar] = Foo(3,1.000000, world)

scala> b1 add b2
res1: Foo[Bar] = Foo(5,4.000000,hello world)
```

Now `add` is type safe. You could then use a type class to get the `toString` to display the `Kind`.

Comment: I like the "parameter as label" idea, for type safety.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @paradigmatic's answer, if you want to be able to support operations that are specific to each `Bar` (e.g. different `toString`), you can go one step further and make `Kind` a typeclass.

```
trait Kind[T] { def name : String }
trait Bar
implicit object BarHasKind extends Kind[Bar] { val name = "Bar" }

class Foo[T : Kind](val i : Int, val d : Double, val s : String) {
  def add(f : Foo[T]) = new Foo[T](i + f.i, d + f.d, s + f.s)
  override def toString = implicitly[Kind[T]].name + "(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)
}

scala> val b1 = new Foo[Bar](2, 3.0, "hello")
b1: Foo[Bar] = Bar(2,3.000000,hello)

trait Biz
implicit object BizHasKind extends Kind[Biz] { val name = "Biz" }

scala> val b2 = new Foo[Biz](1, 1.0, "One")
```

It is just as type safe as before:

```
scala> b1 add b2
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Foo[Biz]
  required: Foo[Bar]

scala> b2 add b2
resN: Foo[Biz] = Biz(2,2.000000,OneOne)
```

For any property that you wish to be dependent on the tag, declare them abstractly in `Kind` and provide the implementations in the implicit objects.

Comment: Interesting.  What's the advantage of your "implicitly" approach over declaring a 'def name = "Foo"' method inside Foo, and having Bar and Biz override it?

Comment: It is not really an advantage, I was just trying to show that you can achieve exactly that even in a setting with no inheritance, similar to the one proposed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The approach with type parametrisation has a limitation in that it doesn't allow you to extend functionality in a natural way which is inheritance. So, an alternative approach could be an override-able factory method (which is simply a delegate to the constructor):

```
class Foo(val i: Int, val d: Double, val s: String) {

  protected def create(i: Int, d: Double, s: String) = new Foo(i, d, s)

  def add[A <: Foo](f: A) = create(i + f.i, d + f.d, s + f.s)

  override def toString = "Foo(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)
}

class Bar(i: Int, d: Double, s: String) extends Foo(i,d,s) {

  protected override def create(i: Int, d: Double, s: String) = new Bar(i, d, s)

  override def toString = "Bar(%d,%f,%s)".format(i,d,s)

  // additional methods...

}

println( new Foo(10, 10.0, "10") add new Bar(10, 10.0, "10") )
println( new Bar(10, 10.0, "10") add new Foo(10, 10.0, "10") )
```